# input time in web2py

Tags: python, database, time, web2py

I want to take input time to complete a task in format no. of days,hours in web2py. Is there any defined field,type for this in SQLField.
time module in python allows only max 24 hours time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Field(...'time') only allows 24 hours and there is no specific type for timeinterval. Yet you can make define one using:

```
 timeinterval = SQLCustomType(....)
```

and use it as

```
 Field('name',type=timeinterval, widget=....)
```

You can also make your own widget to handle it.

Please ask on the web2py mailing list so we keep the info in one place. I will be happy to provide a complete example.